# How to ensure coherent choices of representatives in an e-graph?

Tags: compilers, optimization, e-graphs

[E-graphs](https://egraphs-good.github.io/) are a neat intermediate representation for program transformations and optimisations, which group program terms into equivalence classes (e-classes). An optimising compiler can then select the "best" representative from each e-class during code generation.

However, in some circumstances there may be two or more e-classes, where the correctness of the generated code depends on corresponding representatives being chosen from each class; i.e. the choice of representatives is not independent. For example, suppose our program has a set of small natural numbers, and we want the compiler to consider two possible representations: either a standard set data structure, or a [bitmask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array). In that case, we have the following semantic equivalences:

- `my_set = set()` is equivalent to `my_mask = 0`
- `my_set.add(x)` is equivalent to `my_mask |= 1 << x`
- `y in my_set` is equivalent to `(my_mask & (1 << y)) != 0`

In order for the generated code to be correct, the compiler must consistently choose either the former or the latter representative from each e-class. If we select `my_mask |= 1 << x` from one e-class and `y in my_set` from another, then the generated code will be incorrect (even if the compiler knew to declare both variables). Put another way, the members of each e-class are only equivalent depending on which representatives are chosen from other e-classes.

How can an optimisation like this be implemented correctly using e-graphs?

Comment: A valid e-graph has a "congruence invariant," which means that an equivalence between `x` and `y` must also imply an equivalence between `f(x)` and `f(y)`. Performing these rewrites (`set()` => `0`, `set.add(x)` => `set | (1 << x)`, etc) each individually violates this invariant and so is incompatible with e-graphs in this form.

Comment: @rpjohnst Sure ─ so how can this kind of optimisation be performed correctly using e-graphs? Or can it not?

Comment: Well, phrased the other way, it can be performed using e-graphs if and only if you can organize the language in such a way that these rewrites are "local" and preserve congruence. (If I knew of an obvious way to do this or reason that it was impossible, I would have written an answer- short of that, I'm just pointing to the relevant invariant.)

Comment: In practice, you'd have a local type context, and you'd commit to one of the possible types prior to extraction; then, type-guided extraction is possible (at least `egg` supports this...) However, the only way to know which commitment is more efficient would be to perform two extractions and compare their cost, which would lead to combinatorial explosion. I can write a complete answer later, if nobody else gets to it.

Comment: @rpjohnst That sounds like an answer, not a comment—please post it as one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create one whole (sub) e-graph for the standard set version and another whole (sub) e-graph for the bitmask version.  These two e-graphs fragments are then equivalent.  Further optimization/transformation proceeds as normal, considering each of the two (sub) e-graphs, and finally the only option for later code generation is to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 5):

An e-graph does not just group terms into equivalence classes, but *congruence classes.* This means that an equivalence between terms `x` and `y` also implies an equivalence between terms `f(x)` and `f(y)`.

Congruence is important because e-graphs implicitly rely on it every time a rewrite is applied. All terms that use the rule's LHS are also immediately rewritten to use the RHS, and vice versa, because merging two e-classes preserves all uses of both.

Your example does not preserve congruence, and this will cause problems long before extraction time. For example, rewriting the term `set()` to `0` would also imply that `x + 0` should be rewritten to `x + set()` (using `x + _` for `f`).